# How to deploy EJB module as a module under MODULES folder in wildfly AS

Tags: java, wildfly-8, ejb-3.2, jboss-modules

I have a jar containing EJBs say `EJBTest.jar` and have deployed it as a module under `modules` folder along with `module.xml`in wildfly application server. 
 In the WAR which is the consumer of EJBs, I have added a reference to the EJB module `<module name="com.test.ejb" />` under `<dependencies>` in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

I am getting `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:` from which I am obviously getting that the EJB module jar `EJBTest.jar` is not installed properly under `modules` folder of wildfly application server.

I have a doubt that whether EJB module can installed as a module in wildfly. I have a bean interface and bean implementation annotated with `@remote` and `@stateless` respectively. Am I missing anything ? Or Is is not possible to deploy or install EJB module as a module in wildfly ? Please help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can deploy EJBs as modules in any version of WildFly.

You can however install ejb jar files as regular deployments. ie. You can deploy an ejb-jar file in the same way that you deploy WAR or EAR files.

Is there any reason that you cannot do this?

Comment: Many thanks .. Steve. I am getting that EJBs cannot be deployed as a module which means you will not get trace on EJB deployment and JNDI names on the server startup. What do you refer in this line - "You can however install ejb jar files as regular deployments.". Can you help me to understand more as I doubt it does make difference if EJB jar files is installed and this means just a jar in the "modules" directory and nothing related to EJB stuffs happens on server startup.